# How can I test network errors in fetch api?

Tags: javascript, sinon, chai

I have been successfully able to test a resolved promise on a simple application I have been working on to learn ES6 but been having issues testing the case where there may be network errors.

I wrote this test case:

```
import {Weather} from '../js/weather';

import chai from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import * as chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

let assert = chai.assert;
let should = chai.should;

describe('weatherbot-1', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        sinon.stub(window, 'fetch');

        let data = '{"cod": "400", "message": "Nothing to geocode"}';
        let res = new window.Response(data, {
            ok: false,
            status: 400,
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        window.fetch.returns(Promise.reject(res));
    });

    afterEach(function () {
       window.fetch.restore();
    });

    it('should ensure that promise is rejected', function () {
        let weather = new Weather(0, 0);

        return assert.isRejected(weather.getWeather(), 'Rejected');
    });
});
```

The method in question is:

```
getWeather() {
        let headers = new Headers();

        let init = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: headers,
            cache: 'default'
        };

        let url = 'http://localhost:8080/weather?lat=' + '' + '&lon=' + this.longitude;

        return fetch(url, init).then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        }).catch((error) => {
            return error;
        });
}
```

For testing the promise, I am using `chai-as-promised` & `chai` with `mocha` & `sinon` to stub the `fetch` api.

Whenever I run the test I get this error:

```
AssertionError: expected promise to be rejected with an error including 'Rejected' but it was fulfilled with { type: 'default',
      url: '',
      redirected: false,
      status: 400,
      ok: false,
      statusText: 'OK',
      headers:
       { append: [Function: append],
         delete: [Function: delete],
         get: [Function: get],
         getAll: [Function: getAll],
         has: [Function: has],
         set: [Function: set],
         keys: [Function: keys],
         values: [Function: values],
         entries: [Function: entries],
         forEach: [Function: forEach] },
      body: {},
      bodyUsed: false,
      clone: [Function: clone],
      arrayBuffer: [Function: arrayBuffer],
      blob: [Function: blob],
      json: [Function: json],
      text: [Function: text] }
```

From what it looks like, the `Promise.reject()` may not be working properly. Is there any other way I could test network errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in `getWeather`, not the test:

```
return fetch(url, init)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    return error;
  })
```

`Promise#catch` returns a *resolved* Promise, because its job is to handle errors. The rest of the application should be able to function after catching a rejection, just like with `try/catch`.

If you want the rejection to reach the test, your code shouldn't catch the rejection:

```
return fetch(url, init)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
```

In general you should only `catch` where you can properly handle the error. In this example you might want to handle the rejection in a view where you can display an error message.

Also, your code models an invalid situation. `fetch` returns a *resolved* Promise for all valid HTTP responses including non-200 status.

It does reject when it cannot make a connection at all, e.g. `fetch("http://sdfdsfsd")`. In this case it rejects with an `Error` object.

To properly test a `fetch` rejection you should simulate this condition and have the stub return `Promise.reject(new Error("a message"))`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I removed the `catch`, but I am getting a new error: 

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
     at Object.compatibleMessage (test/rejectedPromise.js:825:254)
     at test/rejectedPromise.js:8036:1432
     at <anonymous>`

Comment: That sounds like an error in `assert.isRejected`. I expect it assumes the rejection value to be an `Error` with a String `message` property. Does the error go away if you add a `message` to your rejection? I know that won't be a representative `fetch` rejection, but it'll help diagnose the issue.

Comment: In fact reading your code some more - that Promise wouldn't reject with `fetch`. `fetch` returns a resolved Promise for valid HTTP responses with non-200 error codes.

Comment: @thedeliciousmuffin depends what you want to test. You could have separate "resolves with 400" and "rejects with TypeError" test. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I see, thanks for such a detailed answer! I definitely learned something about promises. BTW, is there a comprehensive source where I can learn more about promises?

Answer (score 1):

The catch clause in the `getWeather` function returns a new, fulfilled promise. Basically, catch takes away your ability to test for rejection. What you *can* do, is use a spy for the rejection handler, and then test it is called.